# Cycles isn’t rendering fire/smoke simulations

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, smoke-simulation, fire

I have an animation with fire+smoke, but when I render it no fire or smoke shows up and I don’t know the problem, I’m using cycles and the domain has a shader for it. Any help?

Comment: Have you baked the simulation?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the domain shader? and maybe provide the details on how you created the fire+smoke and if you have baked the simulation. there are many issues that could cause your description of the problem, so extra information will help us find the actual problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes, I’ve baked it

Comment: Ok so I’ve figured out it only renders if the flow object is visible in the render

Comment: @Cabbage I don't know what you've done actually, because it usually renders without the flow object being visible. I just tested it, the flow object isn't necessary for rendering.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I started manually adding the domain and flow but after learning it didn’t come with a shader I used quick effects instead, I’m not sure what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, bake all the data BEFORE disabling the emitter otherwise data won’t bake and won’t render.