Why won't my smoke animation work?
I'm trying to create cigarette smoke and it never works. I've looked at multiple tutorials to try and understand what I'm doing wrong but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any suggestions?
Image 1: I've selected a few things so you can see what's part of the smoke simulation

Image 2: With only the domain selected you can see some of the setup on the right

Image 2a: Only the domain is selected and I scrolled down further to show more of the setup on the right

Image 2b: Only the domain is selected and I scrolled down to show the last of the setup within 'physics'

Image 3: Only the object that will be dissolved is selected to show the setup on the right

Image 3a: Only the object that will be dissolved is selected to show the last of the setup within 'physics'


Do you have a texture assigned to the object?

@Starry-EyedDonut I'm assuming you're referring to the small puck-like object that dissolves to become the smoke? No, I didn't create a texture for it.

You haven't really described your problem, so I'm not quite sure what to suggest. Is the smoke not rendering? Is it not showing up in the Material tab? Does the simulation not run when you hit play?

@Starry-EyedDonut There is no smoke visible at all. I press play, but nothing happens. It took 3 hours to "bake" so I'm assuming something happened?

@Starry-EyedDonut I just checked and nothing is showing up in the Material's tab.

So nothing shows up when you try to render it? If so, then my guess would be that you need to assign a texture/material to your smoke domain.

@Starry-EyedDonut I tried assigning a material to the object and the smoke is still not rendering.

See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52740/problem-when-rendering-fire-and-smoke-in-blender-render?rq=1

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272061/cycles-isn-t-rendering-fire-smoke-simulations?rq=1

@Starry-EyedDonut You were right! I needed to assign a material. I had added a Principled BSDF shader instead of a Principled Volume shader. I had glanced at the smoke material section of the Blender manual too quickly and thought I read to add 'Principled BSDF' to the smoke material. I also ended up getting rid of the domain and smoke material and instead, created a new dissolve object and used Quick Smoke. Thank you for your help!

No problem. I'm glad I was able to help you. :) Would you like me to put "assign material" as the correct answer for future users to see?

@Starry-EyedDonut Yes! Please do so.

Done. :) Let me know if you'd like me to edit my post and add the part of the answer that you figured out.

@Starry-EyedDonut Go for it! Whatever you think would be the most helpful to anyone who stumbles upon my question.

Since I only suggested the solution and you were the one that came up with the complete solution, maybe you should post your own answer. I don't want to take credit for the part that you figured out. :)

The solution was to assign a material to the object. See comments for further details.

Hi. Please include the further details from the comments to your answer because comments can be deleted anytime.
